# One-to-many nested attributes in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nested-attributes, nomethoderror

This is not a question, but hopefully someone can benefit from it.

When you try to create or modify a one-to-many nested association make sure that you're passing an array.
If you're getting

> NoMethodError (undefined method `[]' for...

and you're working with a one-to-many nested association this might be your problem.
I didn't find an explanation for this when searching for this error so maybe this will help speed up someone else's development.

For example, I have a Person model with

```
has_many :person_images
accepts_nested_attributes_for :person_images
```

In order to create a new person and associated person_image I do the following.

```
@person = Person.create(:full_name=>@person_name, :person_images_attributes=>[{:image=>person_image}])
```

Notice the [] around {:image=>person_image}. If you have a one-to-many you must have this. So the following doesn't work and produces the undefined method '[]' error.

```
@person = Person.create(:full_name=>@person_name, :person_images_attributes=>{:image=>person_image})
```

Also, in my views I'm having to name my inputs like this

```
<input type="file" name="person[person_images_attributes][0][image]">
```

It doesn't work without the [0].

I'm new to Rails. I hope this helps other beginners and if someone has a better explanation or a more efficient way to do this I'd be grateful for your comments.

For details see  [Rails API on Nested Attributes](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/NestedAttributes/ClassMethods.html)

Comment: It is just confusing that I need to read all those notes to discover that you do not have any question here.

Comment: Thanks m4risU. Have edited to make it clear.

Answer (score 0):

Use formtastic for creating forms, it will handle those [0] things you write about.

See here:

http://railscasts.com/episodes/184-formtastic-part-1
http://railscasts.com/episodes/185-formtastic-part-2

And If you are new to RoR those are really good sites to learn from.

http://railscasts.com
http://guides.rubyonrails.org/

By the way it seems to me that you have little twisted relationships in Person model.
You probably used

```
has_many :person_images
```

But you use [0] to get the first one.